# docker wordpress container can't connect to mysql container

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

I'm at a loss here as to not only why this isn't working but how to further troubleshoot it. I'm new to docker, so could be something obvious, but I can't find it. I did look over some other links here which could be considered "duplicate questions" and nothing helped.

My playground setup:

**mysql container named**: "db"
**phpmyadmin container named**: phpmyadmin
**wordpress container named**: domain-blog

All containers are in a bridge network **docker0**

At this stage I'm starting all containers individually, but I am ensuring the database is up and running prior to running wordpress.

The string to start the wordpress container:

```
docker run --name="domain-blog" -d \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306 \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=domain_user \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=testedpassword \
-e WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=domain_blog \
-e WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX=astring \
--network=docker0 \
-p 8081:80 \
--restart always \
wordpress
```

What I've tried:

- I can log in as `root` with `rootpassword` from phpmyadmin navigating via `hostip:8080`.
- I can log in as `domain_user`, using the `testedpassword` from phpmyadmin.
- Confirmed I can add a new table when logged in as domain_user.
- I have spun up an ubuntu container and installed network tools, can ping all containers.
- I installed `iputils-ping` directly on the wordpress container and can ping `db` using `ping db`. Ping is hitting, but also confirmed that the db is resolving to the correct ip address.
- `cat wp-config.php` shows that user, host(db:3306), password, and database are all being passed through as I'd expect.

I used phpmyadmin when I created the new user/password, database, and added permissions for the user to that database. The user is set to log in from `%`.

The error I'm getting on not being able to access the database is when trying to navigate to the blog via `hostip:8081` Exact error: `Error establishing a database connection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it and feeling rather dumb about it, but in the spirit of education...

When I entered the username/password into mysql via phpmyadmin, the default in the admin interface is to use `Caching sha2 authentication`.

I reset the password using Native Mysql Authentication... It works no problem now.